# What is the right phrase to express "I speed up and repair slow computers"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases, phrase-choice

I want to express that **I speed up and repair slow computers** but I am not sure what phrase I should use.

If I wouldn't want to use the word "Slow", then the phrase

> Computer speed up and repair

would do the magic, but I want to use word "Slow" because I only repair the slowness of computer. And yes, I have to use the word "Repair" too because of the keyword preferences.

I am thinking of using

> Slow computer speed up and repair

but isn't that confusing? It could mean both

> I speed up and repair slow computer

OR

> I speed up and repair computer slowly

What phrase should I use? Any ideas?

Comment: Most of your alternatives are syntactically or idiomatically invalid, but I suspect that *all* short ways of combining ***repair*** and ***speed up*** suffer from the same "potential ambiguity" when used together with ***slow** computers* (i.e. - that you don't repair fast computers, only slow ones). That's the only specific aspect of "English usage" I can see here. In practice, no-one would be in any doubt as to what *Slow computer speed up and repair* actually means, since it would be ridiculous to suppose you can't repair a broken computer unless it's inherently slow even after fixing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers how about phrase "Speed up and repair of computer"? Is that okay?

Comment: I improve the performance of slow computers.

Comment: It's either *Speed up and repair of **computers*** (plural noun) or ***Computer** speed up and repair* (singular noun used "adjectivally").

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you! I used _Speed up and repair of slow computers_. :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more accurate, and less ambiguous, English phrase would be:

> I repair computers with problems that make them slow.

Or, without using the word slow:

> I repair computers with performance issues.

None of the other variations you suggest indicate that the problem being addressed *is* the slowness. In other words, they are interpreted as "I speed up computers. I also repair computers."

(If you weren't forced to use *repair*, there are several other options that would work better, including *fix*, *fine tune*, and *optimize*.)

Also note there is nothing wrong with your original statement of what you want to express. In fact, once rephrased slightly, it's the most natural sounding:

> I repair slow computers and make them fast again.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I should have made it more clear - Imagine a business card or simple bio on some website. That's the place where I need to write it. "Offering: Digital marketing, Protection of privacy and personal information on the internet and social media, _____". Instead of _____ one of the phrases mentioned above. Something like "I repair..." isn't suitable imho.

Comment: Using "Slow computer speed up and repair" would be misleading as mentioned before so how about "Speed up and repair of slow computer"?

Comment: If you want to keep it as simple as possible, then just: "Repair of slow computers." The fact that you're repairing a slow computer implies that it will be fast again when you're done with it. (Grammatically, you could use "slow-computer repair," but most people will NOT pay attention to the hyphen or interpret it correctly.)

Comment: Sounds good. But adding "Speed up" will do not harm, am I right? Want to use it for the sake of keywords.

Comment: Most likely, "speed up and repair slow computers" would not be misinterpreted. (Although I find it redundant.) Another possibility is "speed up / repair slow computers." That removes the possibly ambiguous "and."